# Chat messages do not show up, unless I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React/Redux Chat messenger application, and my goal is display messages as soon as a user types it into the input.  However, the messages do not display until after I refresh the page.  ActiveChat is the parent component, Input is the text field, and Messages displays the messages.  AddMessageToStore is the reducer Function.  I've tried adding a useEffect in the message component, but it still hasn't shown up properly, and I'm stuck on how else to approach this.

```
const ActiveChat = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { user } = props
  const conversation = props.conversation || {}

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Re-rendered')
  }, [props.messages])

  return (
    <Box className={classes.root}>
      {conversation.otherUser && (
        <>
          <Header
            username={conversation.otherUser.username}
            online={conversation.otherUser.online || false}
          />
          <Box className={classes.chatContainer}>
            <Messages
              messages={conversation.messages}
              otherUser={conversation.otherUser}
              userId={user.id}
            />
            <Input
              otherUser={conversation.otherUser}
              conversationId={conversation.id}
              user={user}
            />
          </Box>
        </>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    conversation:
      state.conversations &&
      state.conversations.find(
        (conversation) =>
          conversation.otherUser.username === state.activeConversation,
      ),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ActiveChat)
```

```
const Messages = (props) => {
  const { messages, otherUser, userId } = props

  //add a useEffect?
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Message added', messages)
  }, [props])

  return (
    <Box>
      {messages.map((message) => {
        const time = moment(message.createdAt).format('h:mm')
        console.log(userId)
        return message.senderId === userId ? (
          <SenderBubble key={message.id} text={message.text} time={time} />
        ) : (
          <OtherUserBubble
            key={message.id}
            text={message.text}
            time={time}
            otherUser={otherUser}
          />
        )
      })}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const { postMessage, otherUser, conversationId, user } = props

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // add sender user info if posting to a brand new convo, so that the other user will have access to username, profile pic, etc.
    const reqBody = {
      text: event.target.text.value,
      recipientId: otherUser.id,
      conversationId,
      sender: conversationId ? null : user,
    }

    await postMessage(reqBody)
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormControl fullWidth hiddenLabel>
        <FilledInput
          classes={{ root: classes.input }}
          disableUnderline
          placeholder="Type something..."
          value={text}
          name="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    postMessage: (message) => {
      dispatch(postMessage(message))
    },
  }
}
```

```
export const addMessageToStore = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload
  console.log(sender)
  // if sender isn't null, that means the message needs to be put in a brand new convo
  if (sender !== null) {
    const newConvo = {
      id: message.conversationId,
      otherUser: sender,
      messages: [message],
    }
    newConvo.latestMessageText = message.text
    return [newConvo, ...state]
  }
```

```
const sendMessage = (data, body) => {
  socket.emit("new-message", {
    message: data.message,
    recipientId: body.recipientId,
    sender: data.sender,
  });
};

// message format to send: {recipientId, text, conversationId}
// conversationId will be set to null if its a brand new conversation
export const postMessage = (body) => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = saveMessage(body);

    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
      dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message));
    }

    sendMessage(data, body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: What is postMessage prop on Input component? By "as soon as a user types it into the input", do you mean when the user submits the form?

Comment: It is a function I exported from another file.  I added the code of that function into the post.  And it is an Input from Material UI, as soon the user types in their message and presses Enter, the message should display right away.

Comment: And how are you getting the state from redux?

Comment: I am getting state through mapStateToProps, making an API call to a PostGres DB